# How to configure custom behavior on asp.net client consuming wcf restful service

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I'm new to WCF Restful services. I have a wcf restful service working as expected. I'm trying to hook custom authentication using request headers. I'm trying to hook message inspectorson both the service and client. The server part works as expected. My question is on the client configuration as the the message inspector BeforeSendRequest method is not invoked. I do not have a reference to restful service. My web.config is asfollows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8089/RestService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomEndpointBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfRestfulService.IAtlasService"
        name="webHttpBinding_IRestService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomEndpointBehavior">
          <ClientAuthenticationMessageInspector />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMessageInspector" type="CLientAuthorization.MessageHeaderBehaviorExtention, CLientAuthorization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Am I missing something on this configuration?

Comment: what to you mean about server and client? MessageInspector works over Wcf infrastructure, in server, your client only consume the service.
You can add headers in client side (put some authentication information as you want) before send the message.

Comment: By server I was referring to the service. After digging even more I could realize that custom behaviors are not possible for http client consuming wcf rest. The issue here was I do not have a proxy to wcf restful service. I resorted to inheriting HttpHandler and overriding SendAsync function.